# For which values of x does the power series converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image]

First, I know that the series converges when |x+2| < R and diverges when |x+2| > R. So now I have that the radius of convergence is somewhere between 2 and 3. However, this doesn't really give me too good of an indication of the interval of convergence. I would say that since 2 < R < 3 and a=2, then the interval of convergence would be 0 < x < 5, but please correct me on that if I am wrong. I'm kind of just taking a shot in the dark on that one.

So, I'm lead to believe that a and c would be divergent and b and d would be convergent. I just am in need of more insight on this because I'm trying to explain it to someone else but it has been years since I learned the topic so I'm very unsure of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The power series must be convergent when $x$ satisfies that $-R <x+2< R$, and be divergent
when $x <-R$ and $x>R$ and be unkown when $x+2=-R$ or $x+2=R$, where $2\le R \le 3$.

So (a) is convergent; $b$ is divergent; $c$ and $d$ are unknown.

Comment: Just a question to make sure I've got this correct. So when x=-3, x+2=-1 which falls between -2 and 2 which is the smallest possible interval of convergence so it converges. Then when x=2, x+2=4 which falls outside of -3 to 3 which is the largest possible interval of convergence so diverges. Then when x=-4, we have x+2=-2 which is a problem because R is possibly equal to -2. And lastly, if x=1, x+2=3 and since R is possibly equal to 3 we also have a problem.